bash error message seemingly comes from environment instead of from bash itself when executing inside a function
Consider the following simple bash script
cd nowhere

This results in an error message something like
my-script.sh: line 1: cd: nowhere: No such file or directory

So far so good.  This makes sense.  Let's tweak it a bit, by wrapping the cd in a function:
function go_nowhere { cd nowhere; }
go_nowhere

We get the same error message.  This still makes sense.  Let's try a subshell instead of using a function.
bash -c 'cd nowhere'

Again, similar error message, but now bash "signs" the error message in its own name instead of our script's name:
bash: line 1: cd: nowhere: No such file or directory

So far, everything still makes sense.  Now let's do both!  We'll wrap cd in a function, and run that function in a subshell:
function go_nowhere { cd nowhere; }
export -f go_nowhere
bash -c 'go_nowhere'

Now are message is a bit different.  First, the line number is "line 0" instead of line 1.  This makes sense: since we used "export", that means from the perspective of the subshell, the function was defined "before the first line" since it was inherited from its parent.  But the other difference is weirder:
environment: line 0: cd: nowhere: No such file or directory

What is environment?  I am not running any program called "environment" so why is bash printing an error message that claims to be coming from such a program?  Is it trying to tell me that the error is in a function, which bash inherited from the environment?  We can test that theory:
function go_nowhere { cd nowhere; }
bash -c "`declare -f`; go_nowhere"

The line number is now bigger again, but the error message is still "signed" as environment:
environment: line 3: cd: nowhere: No such file or directory

Now I really don't get it.  It did NOT get this function from the environment.  So where is the string environment coming from?  Note that this is not specific to scripts... this can be reproduced interactively from the prompt: an error inside a function in a subshell gets reported as from environment and I have no idea why

It did NOT get this function from the environment -- but it did! export -f stores function definitions in environment variables.

Extending Shawn's comment: export -f in the parent shell stores the function in that shell's environment (as a weirdly-named env variable), and when you run bash as a subprocess (note: technically not a subshell, that's subtly different) it inherits that environment, and extracts the function definition from it. So from that bash subprocess' point of view, the function did come from the environment.

@Shawn: I think the OP's point is that although bash -c originally got the function from the environment, it subsequently redeclared it (when it ran the output of declare -f), which means that the new version is not from the environment. (Clearly something about this reasoning isn't working out, but it sounds right!)


What is environment?

It is a hardcoded string in bash source code here: https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/make_cmd.c#L804 .
  /* Assume that shell functions without a source file before the shell is
     initialized come from the environment.  Otherwise default to "main"
     (usually functions being defined interactively) */
  if (temp->source_file == 0)
    temp->source_file = shell_initialized ? "main" : "environment";

Do not use backticks. Prefer $(..). Check your code with shellcheck.
You can get the other string "main" by reading from stdin. shell_initialized means the shell is ready to read interactive input.
$ LC_ALL=C bash -s <<<"$(declare -f go_nowhere); go_nowhere"
main: line 3: cd: nowhere: No such file or directory


How can we explain the output of this command : LC_ALL=C bash -s <<<"go_nowhere; $(declare -f go_nowhere); go_nowhere"

hi @Philippe I do not understand. What is there to explain? What requires an explanation? What is confusing to you in the output? What is the output you are getting? https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/error.c#L96 is also relevant.

On the output, one line contains environment, the other main. If shell_initialized is the same when both run, how can we explain the difference ?

You exported the function export -f go_nowhere, so the initial call comes from environment, loaded on bash startup before shell_initialized is set, before interactivity is loaded. In contrast, if you do not export, the first line will have bash: line 1: go_nowhere: command not found. shell_initailized is set pretty late https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/shell.c#L822 . I suspect functions are loaded somewhere in shell_initialize()

So it's just a heuristic, and in this case it misfired.  Makes sense.  Thank you!!

And I actually do use shellcheck, it is a lifesaver...  But I ignore this particular warning... the backtick syntax is just so much lighter!  It is less visually obtrusive (actually one could argue it is almost invisible and hence TOO unobtrusive).  And it is easier on the fingers (0 shifted characters vs 3).  Nesting it is a total disaster, but I don't do that anyway.  (Turns out backslashes act weird too... didn't realize that.)
